# Glove Word Embeddings supported languages

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, word-embedding

I started experimenting with word embeddings, and I found some results which I don't know how to interpret.

I first used an English corpus for both training and testing and afterwards, I used the English corpus for training and a small French corpus for testing (all corpora have been annotated for the same binary classification task). In both cases, I used the pre-trained on tweets Glove embeddings.

As the results in the case where I also used the French corpus improved (by almost 5%, reaching ~accuracy = 0.8), I was wondering if Glove was trained on multilingual data.

I haven't seen anyone making this statement, in contrast to FastText, for example, where you have embeddings for different languages.

Comment: https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/ has links to source data for their pre-trained word vectors. The main ones seem to be exclusively in English but I have not looked at the actual data. I suppose the Common Crawl data for example could include other languages. I'm guessing having multiple languages doesn't typically cause much harm, and might actually be useful in scenarios like yours. On the other hand, it does seem like they *intended* for the models to be for English.

Comment: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~afm/projects/multilingual_embeddings.html has separate vectors for a number of languages.